# List View on click navigate to another page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, navigation

I have a ListView and I would like to make the list items clickable. My idea is that when the user clicks on an item, it will be directed to another page. Each bottom should leads to different screen. I'm having trouble implementing it, I don't know what to use ontap. What should I do? Should I use ListTile instead of ListView?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/PerformancePulses.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: ListViewHome()
    );

  }
}
class ListViewHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final titles = ["Performance Pulses",
     "Admin Indicator",];
  final icons = [Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined, Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: titles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(titles[index]),
                  leading: const CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          "https://wcs.smartdraw.com/chart/img/basic-bar-graph.png?bn=15100111840")),
                  trailing: Icon(icons[index])));
        });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a click listener on the card and navigate to the screen you want

Sample

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:untitled1/PerformancePulses.dart';

   void main() {
     runApp(MyApp());
   }
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    ),
    home: ListViewHome()
  );

    }
  }
class ListViewHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final titles = ["Performance Pulses",
 "Admin Indicator",];
 final icons = [Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined, 
 Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined];
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ListView.builder(
     itemCount: titles.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {

      return InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          //this is where you navigate to new screen
          // SecondScreen() should be name of the second screen you created
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(
              
            )),
          );
        },
        child: Card(
            child: ListTile(
                title: Text(titles[index]),
                leading: const CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        "https://wcs.smartdraw.com/chart/img/basic-bar-graph.png?bn=15100111840")),
                trailing: Icon(icons[index]))),
      );
    });

   }
 }
```

Comment: it was showing error when i have adding new screen

Comment: SecondScreen() is just what i added, create a new dart screen with either stateless or statefull widget and replace the name of the SecondScreen with the name you give the widget..you should be fine

Comment: i have Crete it but it was showing error  https://ibb.co/nDZ82Ws check the image

Comment: you have to import the class.. if you on mark, use option + return .. just like normal importing a class

Comment: I cant understand can you tell me in detail

Comment: import your class like import '../SecondScreen.dart';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247665/discussion-between-babar-ali-and-muraino).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `Card` widget into `GestureDetector` and you have `onTap`

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourRoute()));
  },
  child: Card(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(titles[index]),
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
      "https://wcs.smartdraw.com/chart/img/basic-bar-graph.png?bn=15100111840")),
      trailing: Icon(icons[index])
    )
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

first create model class for your list item like this:

```
class ItemModel {
 final String title;
 final Widget route;

 ItemModel({@required this.title,@required this.route });

}
```

then define you list like this:

```
final _list = [ ItemModel(
title: "Performance Pulses", route: SomeWidget()),
    ItemModel(
title: "Admin Indicator", route: SomeWidget2()),];
```

and your List would like to be this:

```
    ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _list[index].route));
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(_list[index].title),
                      leading: const CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              "https://wcs.smartdraw.com/chart/img/basic-bar-graph.png?bn=15100111840")),
                      trailing: Icon(icons[index]))),
  );
})
```